# Getting two columns one containing and one not containing a grouped value

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns

My data looks like this -

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| FLIGHT_NO |  FL_DATE  | SERIAL_NO | PILOT_NO |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|       501 | 15-OCT-19 |    456710 |      345 |
|       521 | 16-OCT-19 |    562911 |      345 |
|       534 | 17-OCT-19 |    877694 |      345 |
|       577 | 17-OCT-19 |    338157 |      345 |
|       501 | 14-OCT-19 |    921225 |      346 |
|       534 | 15-OCT-19 |    877694 |      346 |
|       534 | 14-OCT-19 |    338157 |      347 |
|       590 | 16-OCT-19 |    650012 |      347 |
|       531 | 14-OCT-19 |    562911 |      348 |
|       531 | 15-OCT-19 |    562911 |      348 |
|       501 | 16-OCT-19 |    220989 |      349 |
|       521 | 18-OCT-19 |    650012 |      349 |
|       590 | 14-OCT-19 |    562911 |      351 |
|       577 | 18-OCT-19 |    877694 |      351 |
|       590 | 18-OCT-19 |    456710 |      346 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

My aim is to return the total number of flights flying and not flying on 18-oct-19. 
I'm doing it with dual but that doesn't seem to be the correct/best method. 
Can anyone help me do it the correct way?

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(FLIGHT_NO) NO_FLY FROM schd_flight WHERE fl_date = '18-OCT-19') AS FLY, 
(SELECT COUNT(FLIGHT_NO) NO_FLY FROM schd_flight WHERE fl_date  <> '18-OCT-19') AS NO_FLY 
FROM dual;
```

My output -

```
+-----+--------+
| fly | no_fly |
+-----+--------+
|   3 |     12 |
+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `sum` with `case` statement

```
Select 
sum(case when fl_date = '18-OCT-19' then 1 end) fly,
sum(case when fl_date <> '18-OCT-19' then 1 end) no_fly
From schd_flight;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the second query is not necessary, no_fly = total - fly.
So I came up with my solution, may improve the query time :

```
SELECT sub.FLY as FLY, (SELECT count(*) from schd_flight) - sub.FLY as NO_FLY
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(CASE when fl_date = '18-OCT-19' then 1 end) AS FLY 
    from schd_flight
) sub;
```

Not tested yet though.